# How to remove dictionaries in a list which have some duplicate values (but not all)

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

For example, let's say I'm given this list of dictionaries:

```
test1 = {'Count':34, 'Letter':'a', 'Word':'all'}
test2 = {'Count':890, 'Letter':'a', 'Word':'all'}
test3 = {'Count':333, 'Letter':'b', 'Word':'joy'}
test4 = {'Count':2, 'Letter':'a', 'Word':'all'}

test_list = [test1, test2, test3, test4]
```

Ideally, I want to remove all of the dictionaries from the list which have `'Letter':'a'` and `'Word':'all'` with the exception of one, where the one I keep has the largest value of `'Count'`. In this case, I would want the list to be reduced to having only `[test2, test3]`. Is there a simple way to do this?

I've only been able to find resources which can remove duplicates if the entire dictionary is the same, but I haven't found anything for when only a small number of values are the same. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if you have multiple `b` and `joy` entries? Are you removing multiple entries for all groupings, or *just that one group*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to *group* your dictionaries first, then keep only the dictionary with the highest value for `'Count'` in each group. You can use a set to track which groups you have already seen to filter out subsequence dictionaries that fall in the same:

```
grouped = {}
for d in test_list:
    group_key = d['Letter'], d['Word']
    grouped.setdefault(group_key, []).append(d)

test_list = [max(dlist, key=lambda d: d['Count']) for dlist in grouped.values()]
```

This lets you filter the dictionaries in linear time (O(n)).

Note that the output order is not necessarily the input order for Python versions < 3.6; replace `grouped = {}` with `from collections import OrderedDict` and `grouped = OrderedDict()` if order matters.

Demo:

```
>>> test1 = {'Count':34, 'Letter':'a', 'Word':'all'}
>>> test2 = {'Count':890, 'Letter':'a', 'Word':'all'}
>>> test3 = {'Count':333, 'Letter':'b', 'Word':'joy'}
>>> test4 = {'Count':2, 'Letter':'a', 'Word':'all'}
>>> test_list = [test1, test2, test3, test4]
>>> grouped = {}
>>> for d in test_list:
...     group_key = d['Letter'], d['Word']
...     grouped.setdefault(group_key, []).append(d)
...
>>> [max(dlist, key=lambda d: d['Count']) for dlist in grouped.values()]
[{'Count': 890, 'Letter': 'a', 'Word': 'all'}, {'Count': 333, 'Letter': 'b', 'Word': 'joy'}]
```

Comment: A question: your use of `setdefault` can be replaced with `defautdict(list)` correct?

Comment: @pylang: yes, you can use a `defaultdict()` too. I find that a `defaultdict()` can more easily mask bugs due to the implicit creation of values whenever you access a non-existing key, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one-liner:

```
test1 = {'Count':34, 'Letter':'a', 'Word':'all'}
test2 = {'Count':890, 'Letter':'a', 'Word':'all'}
test3 = {'Count':333, 'Letter':'b', 'Word':'joy'}
test4 = {'Count':2, 'Letter':'a', 'Word':'all'}
test_list = [test1, test2, test3, test4]
final_list = [i for i in test_list if (i['Word'] != 'all' and i['Letter'] != 'a') or i['Count'] == max([b['Count'] for b in test_list])]
```

Output:

```
[{'Count': 890, 'Word': 'all', 'Letter': 'a'}, {'Count': 333, 'Word': 'joy', 'Letter': 'b'}]
```